# Асинхронный код в конструкторе

Tags: c#, .net

В общем, допустим есть класс, который имеет некоторое кеширование и асинхронный метод, который позволяет обновить кеш.

Есть классы, которые с этим кешем работают.

НО, есть классы, которые обязаны при работе работать с актуальным кешем => дернуть метод обновления перед самой работой.

По идее, я бы мог бы создать базовый класс с конструктором, который принимает на вход класс с кешем и обязать его дернуть этот метод, а все остальные критические классы наследовались от него.

Однако проблема в том, что он асинхронен... Как я могу решить эту задачу кроме того, что запихать эту логику во все открытые методы критических классов и проверять обновлялся ли кеш?

Comment: а какая связь текста вопроса с заголовком об асинхронном конструкторе? Попробуй добавить пример кода, как ты это сейчас делаешь и как бы ты хотел чтобы было

Comment: [Async OOP 2: Constructors](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html)

Comment: @Grundy Я сейчас просто в каждом критическом классе вызываю этот метод, однако хотелось бы, что бы эта логика была где-то центролизованной и про нее нельзя было забыть. Как мне кажется, конструктор базового класса- это самое лучшее место.

Comment: ты можешь передавать корректные данные в конструктор `new MyClass(await GetData())`

Comment: Согласен с Grundy. Лучше получить актуальные данные до вызова конструктора и передать их в конструктор

Comment: Я обычно в таких случаях делаю цепочный вызов, простой `someClass.Update().Start();` и читается легко и применяется просто и логика разделена на отдельные методы (что тоже весьма удобно). Но такой подход не всегда и не везде нужен.

Comment: @Grundy можно, но не так элегантно. Я рассчитывал, что DI сам все раскидает в нужные места, а потом централизованно в базовом классе это будет вызвано 1 раз.  А в таком виде, придется во внедрении зависимостей распихивать инициализацию данных...=(

Comment: @iluxa1810, ну так этим и должен DI заниматься - он же должен предоставить корректно инициализированный объект

Comment: `НО, есть классы, которые обязаны при работе работать с актуальным кешем => дернуть метод обновления перед самой работой.` это звучит как бизнес требование и должно быть отражено в коде этих классов, а не в путанной логике натягивания кеша на DI.

Comment: @Grundy Хорошо, а в Autofac можно зарегистрировать зависимость и перед тем, как ее вернуть выполнить асинхронный метод?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38242662/2881286