# Асинхронный конструктор класса

Tags: c#, async-await

Всем известно, что асинхронных конструкторов не бывает, ну во всяком случае пока. Что же делать?

Уже есть подобный вопрос [Асинхронный код в конструкторе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1164303/373567), и несмотря на множество безусловно полезных комментов под ним, решения вопроса предлагаются только для промышленных масштабов - [правильные и сложные](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html).

Сидел, ломал голову, как же наиболее просто и безопасно проинициализировать объект, который нельзя использовать до окончания асинхронной операции инициализации внутреннего состояния объекта.

Самое очевидное лобовое решение, которое не подходит по выше указанные условия:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int _data;

    public async Task InitAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        data = 42;
    }

    public int GetData()
    {
        if (_data != 42)
            throw new Exception("Объект не инициализирован, запустите InitAsync(), и дождитесь его завершения");
        return _data;
    }
}
```

То есть проверять при вызове рабочих методов, а корректно ли был проинициализирован объект, и бросать исключение, если нет.

```
var instance = new MyClass();
await instance.InitAsync();
int result = instance.GetData();
```

Решение рабочее, но уязвимо к ошибкам при разработке в случае если разработчик забудет вызвать `InitAsync()` или этот метод не будет вызван по каким-то другим причинам, или в методе инициализации возникнет исключение. В общем, шанс получить нерабочий экземпляр есть, и это плохо.

Есть ли простой способ реализации консистентного решения? Без фабрик, кучи интерфейсов и прочего.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Способ есть, и не смотря на простоту, он оказался для меня неочевидным. А заключается он в скрытии конструктора и создании объекта через статический метод. *Почему я этого решения раньше нигде не встретил? :)*

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int _data;

    private MyClass() // прячу конструктор
    {
    }

    public static async Task<MyClass> CreateAsync()
    {
        var instance = new MyClass();
        await instance.InitAsync();
        return instance;
    }

    private async Task InitAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        data = 42;
    }

    public int GetData()
    {
        return _data;
    }
}
```

Проверять корректность инициализации в рабочих методах теперь нет необходимости, так как за пределами метода `CreateAsync()` непроинициализированный экземпляр не будет существовать.

Работа разработчика сводится к такому коду:

```
var instance = await MyClass.CreateAsync();
int result = instance.GetData();
```

Такое решение мне кажется более целостным и безопасным. Не смог объект проинициализироваться, значит и не будет ссылки на него. А следовательно нелегального вызова `GetData()` не может произойти. Плюс публичное API класса теперь выглядит покороче, что тоже хорошо.

Как быть с `readonly` полями и `get`-only свойствами? А вот так:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly int _data;

    private MyClass(int data)
    {
        _data = data;
    }

    public static async Task<MyClass> CreateAsync()
    {
        int data = await InitAsync();
        return new MyClass(data);
    }

    private static async Task<int> InitAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        return 42;
    }

    public int GetData()
    {
        return _data;
    }
}
```