# Как правильнее дождатся условно бесконечно Task цикла, если он создается в конструкторе класса?

Tags: c#

Задача предполагает что в конструкторе класса будет вызван Task, который с точки зрения бизнес логики должен жить в течение всего жизненного цикла приложения. Но также логика требует убедится, что Task не завершился с исключением. Хотелось также получать исключение наиболее естественным образом. Как решаются подобного рода задачи?

```cs
public class Example
    {
        internal async Task taskExample()
        {
            int count = 0; // тут она очевидно конечная
            while(true)
            {
                if (count == 3) throw new InvalidOperationException(nameof(count));
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                ++count;
            }
        }
        public Example()
        {
            Task task = taskExample(); // Задача старутет. Как её ожидать если она бесконечна ? 
        }
    }
```

Ну например можно примерно как то так.

```cs
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    foreach (var item in tasks)
                    {
                        if (item.IsFaulted is true)
                        {
                            if (item.Exception is null) continue;
                            else
                            {
                                throw item.Exception;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start();
```

Если рассматривать обработку исключений в Task, то вроде некоторые исключения не удастся так обработать.

UPD

В моем пэт проекте метод на самом деле является обёрткой на событием. И обычно когда подписываешься это выглядит примерно так. И как то упускаешь момент.

```
TrayIcon._notifyIcon.MouseClick += NotifyIcon_MouseClick
```

Я вообще то запамятовал что async void не блокирует поток. И он допустим для событий. А где он плох можно почитать по ссылке ниже.

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming

Скрин из пэт проекта. Просто хотел попробовать в реактивном стиле.

[image: Пример обёртки]

Проверил исключения вроде не теряются. И то что их не получится обработать привычным способом не принципиально. Главное что они не потеряны.

Comment: Если задача бесконечная, то чего там ожидать? Обычно такие задачи запускают фоном и забивают на них. Ну а дожидаются именно конечные задачи, например вот в вашем коде вы делаете 3 итерации, после чего кидаете исключение - зачем? Почему не сделать `for` цикл тогда? А так, если у вас крутиться бесконечно цикл, то вам надо позаботиться и о его остановке, в Task'ах за это отвечает `CancellationToken`. Ну а по поводу `Task task = taskExample();` - это не есть хорошо, ибо таски лучше вызывать как `await taskExample();`, будет вам ожидание. Не можете в конструкторе? А зачем тогда в него кидаете..?

Comment: Констуктор класса существует для инициализации начального состояния объекта. Пытаться тудка какую то логику и тем более какие то ожидания чего то засунуть - прямой выстрел себе в ноги.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1430395/184217

Comment: Что толку кидать ссылку на асинхронный конструктор класса, если я не могу дождаться завершения асинхронной операции.

Comment: У задачи есть свойства `Status`, `IsCanceled`, `IsCompleted` и прочее. Периодически опрашивайте их для получения нужной информации. Я не вижу проблемы. / Или сделайте у класса событие наподобие `Completed` и подписывайтесь на него.

Comment: Спасибо. Но кто будет проверять эти статусы после выхода из конструктора? Вероятно только тот  поток который будет специально для этого создан. (не из пула)

Comment: У класса делаем свойство `public Task WorkingTask { get; }` В конструкторе запускаем задачу, ссылку на которую можно получить из этого свойства. А далее с этой задачей можно делать что угодно извне: проверять её свойства, _продолжать_ с помощью `ContinueWith` и т. п.