# Синхронный вызов асинхронного метода?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Возможно, это дубликат, но я не смог найти однозначного ответа. Да и много рецептов попадается для старых версий `.NET Framework`, а в современном `.NET (Core)` что-то могло поменяться.

Итак, имеется легаси код, в котором понатыканы конструкции вида:

```cs
FooAsync().Wait();
...
var result = BarAsync().Result;
```

Мне кажется, что такое обращение с асинхронными методами не является правильным. Где-то мне удалось протащить асинхронность через все уровни и исправить это безобразие на нормальные вызовы через `await`. Но так удалось сделать далеко не везде, где-то на верхнем уровне всё упирается в синхронный код и я не уверен, что я могу его там поменять на асинхронный. Либо там очень много уровней архитектуры где-то выше, которые я тоже не могу сразу все поменять.

Итак, вопрос: как в современных версиях `.NET` рекомендуется **вызывать асинхронный код из синхронного**? Я понимаю, что так то это вообще не рекомендуется, но вот для случаев, когда такого не избежать - как это сделать наиболее правильно? Или может смириться с тем как есть, другие варианты будут ничем не лучше?

P.S. В частности проблема есть с вызовом асинхронного метода в конструкторе класса. Да, есть методики для этого с сокрытием конструктора, но мне кажется, что их невозможно совместить с использованием `DI` фреймворка. Пример:

```cs
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public Foo(ISomething something, IAnother another)
    {
        _something = something;
        _another = another;
        Bar().Wait();
    }
}
...
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ISomething, Something>();
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IAnother, Another>();
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IFoo, Foo>();
```

Comment: *"кажется, что такое обращение с асинхронными методами не является правильным"*, *"понимаю, что так то это вообще не рекомендуется"* - звучит, как будто ОПа держит в заложниках секта "асинхронного" кода. ¿Видимо бывшая в тренде некоторое время назад секта адептов "функционального" кода, пропагандировавшая везде использовать лямбда-выражения и т.п., загнулась?

Comment: [Should I expose synchronous wrappers for asynchronous methods?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/)

Comment: @user7860670 Ну, там дедлоки всякие возможны, ещё что-то такое, не? )  Считается, что лучше не смешивать асинхронный код и синхронный. Особенно в описанном мной сценарии. А при чём тут лямбда-выражения и кто такой ОП? )

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Почитаю с интересом, но статье опять же 12 лет уже, а `.NET` на месте не стоит. Наверняка что-то поменялось с тех пор.

Comment: Да, дедлоки возможны, всё зависит от контекста синхронизации. Если они возникнут, то в статье описаны способы избежания. Простейший способ - выгрузить в другой поток: `Task.Run(() => Library.FooAsync()).Result` - это гарантирует невозможность дедлоков.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не гарантирует. Никто мне не мешает внутри `FooAsync` дёрнуть какой-нибудь `Progress<T>`, который засинкан на UI поток, который вы только что залочили через `.Result`.

Comment: @aepot Ну, `UI` в чистом виде там у меня вроде нет, там веб-сервис разве что, и не сильно загруженный, поэтому, видимо, это всё как-то ещё жило с таким подходом.

Comment: @CrazyElf, ОП это ТС, то есть вы. Наденьте жёлтое платье если вас держат в заложниках.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Да не, ну я просто хочу сделать всё правильно - без внезапных псевдослучайных дедлоков и т.п. Дело не в слепом следовании некой парадигме, а в том, чтобы код работал безглючно.

Comment: [Async OOP 2: Constructors](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) - ещё одна классическая статья.

Comment: ОП - от английского Original Poster. А вот фраза "без внезапных псевдослучайных дедлоков" как-то резко превращает вопрос в проблему XY. Вроде как дедлоки при использовании "асинхронности"  в .NET являются насущной проблемой, но вот вместо того чтобы устранять причину проблемы (навязанные в c# сомнительные встронные средства асинхронности) почему-то советуют добавлять еще больше "асинхронности". Это очень странно.

Comment: @user7860670 Сама по себе асинхронность в C# работает отлично, если понимать, как она работает. Есть тонкости, ну так они в любом языке есть, нигде обычно нельзя мешать между собой концепции.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На самом деле, единственное место, где sync-over-async допустим и используется - это `main`, точка входа в приложение. Но для того чтобы никого не смущать, разработчики .NET уже реализовали обвязку, и теперь можно писать просто.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    // await
}
```

Вот он, верхний уровень. Других верхних уровней нет.

Конечно, есть например Windows Forms, где базовые обработчики событий не поддерживают асинхронность, например

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Foo();
}
```

Но и здесь уже есть готовое решение. Так как асинхронный метод не блокирует UI на время выполнения, следует защитить кнопку до конца выполнения асинхронной операции. Плюс так как кроме `void` вернуть ничего из метода нельзя, нужно перехватить исключения в `async void` методе.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    btn.Enabled = false;
    try
    {
        // await FooAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    btn.Enabled = true;
}
```

Собственно вот и всё решение. Никаких `.Wait()` или `.Result` в коде быть по определению не должно.

Единственный случай, когда разрешается обращение к `.Result` это когда `Task` уже явно завершён, и даже в некоторых случаях это считается более здоровой практикой, чем `await`, но это уже тонкие тонкости.

```
if (task.IsCompleted)
{
    var result = task.Result;
}
```

Поэтому *в случае, если вы отдаёте себе отчёт* в том что делаете, то как временные костыли можете использовать `.Wait()` или `.Result` до тех пор, пока планомерно всё это не перепишете полностью.

Использовать sync-over-async только потому что кажется, что других простых решений нет, крайне не рекомендуется ни при каких обстоятельствах. Ибо в лучшем случае это будет слив ресурсов из-за бессмысленной блокировки потока, в худшем - будете искать дедлоки, возникающие только в полнолуние при параде планет.

---

P. S. В случае с конструкторами решений тоже [несколько](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1430395/373567). Один из них "запустил и забыл".

```
private readonly _initTask;
private string _superImportantValue;

public Foo(ISomething something, IAnother another)
{
    _something = something;
    _another = another;
    _initTask = Bar();
}

private async Task Bar()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    _superImportantValue = "ready";
}
```

Теперь надо в методе, использующем `_superImportantValue` обработать вероятность ошибки.

**Вариант 1** - бросить исключение

```
public void Baz()
{
    if (!_initTask.IsCompleted)
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    // ... _superImportantValue
}
```

**Вариант 2** - всё-таки замёрзнуть

```
public void Baz()
{
    _initTask.Wait();
    // ... _superImportantValue
}
```

Такой вариант допустим, если по логике предполагается, что в 99,9% случаев `_initTask` на момент вызова метода уже готов.

В любом случае если это не идеальное решение, то оно хотя-бы не блочит вам построение приложения в IOC контейнере.

**Вариант 3** - а что, так можно было?

```
public async Task BazAsync()
{
    await _initTask;
    // ... _superImportantValue
}
```

Comment: Имхо, это не ответ на вопрос. Человек спрашивает "Как вызвать", а не "Почему нельзя вызывать".

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov как вызвать он и так знает - `.Wait()` и `.Result`. Вопрос _как в современных версиях .NET рекомендуется вызывать асинхронный код из синхронного?_ Ответ _Использовать sync-over-async только потому что кажется, что других простых решений нет, крайне не рекомендуется ни при каких обстоятельствах._ - это вполне прямой ответ на поставленный вопрос. Обратите внимание на слово "рекомендуется".

Comment: А если я в асинхронном переписывании кода дошёл до конструктора класса и там вызывается теперь асинхронный метод - что делать в этом случае? )  Конструктор же нельзя сделать асинхронным? Я почитал, там предлагают разную магию, но у меня ещё сложность в том, что у меня DI фреймворк используется, и я не уверен, будет ли нормально работать DI, если сильно начать шаманить с конструктором.

Comment: @CrazyElf то что конструктор сделать нельзя асинхронным, совершенно не значит, что вообще ничего сделать нельзя https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1430395/373567, значит надо переписывать так, чтобы с DI проблем не было. Если без fire-and-forget нельзя, значит надо куда-то спрятать `Task` и потом выхватить из него исключение, если вдруг возникло.

Comment: @aepot По идее, последний пример в том ответе должен и с DI фреймворком подружиться, получается? Только понять бы, как его правильно инстанциировать с учётом DI.

Comment: @CrazyElf дополнил ответ.

Comment: Конструктор можно заменить фабричным методом, а он может быть асинхронным. Все вычисления в конструкторе выносятся в асинхронные статические методы. Когда все они отработали, вызывается приватный конструктор, который только переписывает свои параметры в поля. Что-то вроде шаблона Строитель.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy тоже очень хороший вариант, да.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Без кода я плохо в шаблонах проектирования ориентируюсь. Код бы посмотреть. Звучит то отлично )

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)#%D0%A1#

Comment: @CrazyElf ну "фабричный метод" это вполне себе палка, которую можно блосить в гугла, чтобы он принёс гору ссылок не первой свежести на почитать. Кстати, ссылочка выше на ответ про конструкторы - это что-то типа "фабричного метода".

Comment: DI который создаёт промисы вместо реальных объектов - это звучит интересно. :)

Comment: @aepot Варианты в конце ответа добавлены отличные, но проблема в том, что плодами этой инициализации пользуется штук 5 методов класса и неизвестно, в каком порядке они будут вызываться. Получается, в каждом из этих методов придётся дополнительно работать с таском-инициализатором, что уже выглядит не `DRY`. И если потом кто-то будет этот класс дописывать и добавит новый метод, то не факт, что он сообразит такую же проверку вставить. (

Comment: @CrazyElf вы же знаете `IDisposable` и как в начале почти каждого метада в недрах дотнета пишется вызов `CheckDisposed()`, чтобы бросить исключение если `disposed == true`. Вот здесь та же история только про инициализацию. А что поделать? Ну можно конечно перекреститься и `.Wait(); // TODO: refactor this sh*t later!` :)

Comment: Такой подход очень напоминает байки из США, когда в ответ на стрельбу в общественных местах продавци оружия рекомендуют людям носить больше стволов. *"Никаких .Wait() или .Result в коде быть по определению не должно."* - Мне, как выходцу из мира ассмеблера/FORTH/C/C++, где можно достаточно свободно строить свои луна-парки, кажется очень странным, что пользователей c# само существование `.Wait()` или `.Result` ни разу не смущает. Попробуйте для разминки сделать асинхронные вызовы без них.

Comment: @user7860670 `while (true) { }`. Вся эта асинхронщина на банальных колбэках работает.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy https://stackoverflow.com/a/56092832/12888024 можно же зарегать `Func<Task<T>>` или `Task<T>` в DI контейнере.

Comment: Я не возражаю против технической возможности. Я не настоящий сварщик, меня пугают системы настолько сложные, что для их инициализации нужна асинхронность. Хоть я и понимаю что есть сервера конфигурации и, значит, асинхронность при инициализации имеет место быть.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy все асинхронные инициализации - это почти всегда ошибка проектирования. Даже если приложению для нормальной работы нужно стянуть какие-то данные с веба или из БД (если это сервер), это должно происходить за пределами сборки в контейнере. Конструктор класса должен работать быстро, моментально, всё остальное потом.