Создание многопоточности для функции с ожиданием
Есть некая функция, выполняющая отправку сообщений с задержкой, используя авторизационный код, сообщение, и временная задержка между сообщениями, подготовленные определенным пользователем.
Мне необходимо, чтобы когда все данные были введены функция начала свою работу для определенного пользователя и продолжала ее пока он не захочет остановить отправку сообщений.
Но таких запусков функции будет не одно количество, ведь пользователей бота может быть много.
Сначала для решения этой задачи я создал такой код, который делает что-то похожее на то что я хочу сделать:
bool IsPosting = true;
var task = Post();


await task;
static async Task Post()
    
{
    while(IsPosting) {
        Console.WriteLine("Отправка сообщения");

        await Task.Delay(5000); 

       
    }
    
}

Но будет если такой код работать корректно, если запустить таким образом 1000+ задач ?
Как можно реализовать это более лучшим способом ?

Да будет, хотя возможно лучше использовать Task.Run для запуска задач. Главное поменяйте проверку переменной на CancellationToken или как его там, так будет правильнее.

Спасибо за ответ

Как минимум используйте volatile, а лучше CancellationToken.

Вверху ссылки на ответы, в которых вы сможете найти, как правильно создать цикл с помощью токена отмены и как правильно реализовать ограничение на количество одновременно работающих асинхронных задач с семафором и без. Если будут другие вопросы, связанные с этим, задайте их отдельно.

Первым делом я рекомендую вам вынести все параметры (а именно сообщение) из вне, дабы его можно было модифицировать для разных задач. После чего для каждой конкретной задачи создать свой объект-контейнер, который будет хранить информацию об этой задачи, а именно: отправляемое сообщение и отменена ли задача.
В итоге получается примерно такой класс:
class MessageSenderTask
{
    // Сурс для получения токена для отмены задачи
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new();

    // Сообщение, которое мы отправляем
    public string Message = "";

    // Задержка между сообщениями (static потому что она едина для всех)
    public static int Delay = 1000;

    // Отменить задачу
    public void Cancel() => cts.Cancel();

    void SendMessage(string message) =>
        Console.WriteLine(message);

    // Создаём задачу
    Task makeTask(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => new Task(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                SendMessage(Message);
                await Task.Delay(Delay, cancellationToken);
            }
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException) { }
    }, cancellationToken);

    // Создаём запущенную задачу
    public void Start() => makeTask(cts.Token).Start();
}

Пример использования:
var task1 = new MessageSenderTask() { Message = "Hello from task1" };
var task2 = new MessageSenderTask() { Message = "Hello from task2" };

Task.Delay(1000).Wait();

task1.Start();
task2.Start();

Task.Delay(5000).Wait();

task1.Cancel();

task2.Message = "new message";

Task.Delay(5000).Wait();

task2.Cancel();


А вот при использовании CancellationToken можно было бы корректно прекратить задачу даже во время ожидания await Task.Delay(Delay); )

Как минимум используйте volatile, а лучше CancellationToken.

@CrazyElf Если честно, изначально и хотел с ним, но его реализация мне вообще не нравится) Однако про перехват в Task.Delay не подумал, так что всё же изменю ответ

Здесь меня примерно всё триггерит: 1) sync-over-async Task.Delay(5000).Wait(); - это неприличный код, 18+. Если нужно синхронное ожидание, есть Thread.Sleep. 2) использование конструктора new Task, вместо этого следует использовать Task.Run и здесь к следующему пункту: 3) засовывать и без того асинхронный код в поток смысла чуть меньше, чем никакого. Итого: вам стоит подтянуть знания по асинхронке/многопоточке, так как код выглядит древним и местами избыточнным. Если этот код конечно не Chat GPT писал, в этом случае всё ещё хуже, почерк нейронки прослеживается в коде.

cпасибо ну примерно так и сделаю

@aepot 1)Task.Delay(5000).Wait(); находится чисто в примере только потому что я не мог поменять маин метод на асунц, ибо пользовался онлайн компилятором. Да и Task.Wait() не самая худшая конструкция что придумало человечество, ибо этот тот же await, просто без синтаксического сахара.

new Task() я использую, потому что предполагаю, что данный код будет использоваться для условных рассылок с огромным количеством ботов, следовательно для их синхронизации в будущем может понадобиться данная логика как раздельная. Это конечно оверинженеринг, но вполне оправданный как по мне.


@aepot
3) Вопрос стоит про "создание многопоточности для функции с ожиданием", соответственно и код мой многопоточен.
Так что я считаю, что вы немного прикопались с ничего, а понятие о "красивом" коде у всех разные.

Без обид, код слабый. Посмотрите ссылки на дубликаты вверху, там простая реализация бесконечного цикла есть и без ГПТ-шных ошибок. К тому же нет у вас ответа на вопрос как запустить 1000 тасок и не приложить комп. То есть ответили только на половину вопроса с кучей избыточного кода. Что писать вместо Delay.Wait я написал выше.

@aepot Thread сам по себе устаревший. А в чём собственно проблема Task.Result и Task.Wait()?

Ну это основы основ асинхронного программирования, поизучайте, ключевое слово await же зачем-то придумали, вот и разберитесь, зачем. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1571143/373567 Thread не устаревший, он низкоуровневый, в использовании этого класса напрямую смысла нет.
